# Discord Oauth get permissions

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, composer-php, discord

I am trying to get a the oAuth perms of a user, but the discord api for permissions is so confusing to me i want user that are able to kick and ban be able to use the web panel i am building but like if i want the permissions for it it gives me 2 = kick 4 = Ban 2+4 = 6 ... i truely don't understand this because you can get 6 with other perms as well how do i claculate it?

I am already able to get the permissions and the server name now the main part missing is the permissions.

```php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Xwilarg\Discord\OAuth2;
// Sample configuration file, contains the following strings:
// clientId: Client ID of the application
// secret: Secret of the application
// url: The redirect URL (URL called after the user is logged in, must be registered in https://discordapp.com/developers/applications/[YourAppId]/oauth)
$auth = json_decode(file_get_contents('token.json'), true);
$oauth2 = new OAuth2($auth["clientId"], $auth["secret"], $auth["url"]);
if ($oauth2->isRedirected() === false) { // Did the client already logged in ?
    // The parameter can be a combination of the following: connections, email, identity or guilds
    // More information about it here: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources-oauth2-scopes
    $oauth2->startRedirection(['identify', 'guilds']);
} else {
    // If preload the token to see if everything happen without error
    $ok = $oauth2->loadToken();
    if ($ok !== true) {
        // A common error can be to reload the page because the code returned by Discord would still be present in the URL
        // If this happen, isRedirected will return true and we will come here with an invalid code
        // So if there is a problem, we redirect the user to Discord authentification
        $oauth2->startRedirection(['identify', 'connections']);
    } else {
        // ---------- USER INFORMATION
        $answer = $oauth2->getUserInformation(); // Same as $oauth2->getCustomInformation('users/@me')
        if (array_key_exists("code", $answer)) {
            exit("An error occured: " . $answer["message"]);
        } else {
            echo "Welcome " . $answer["username"];
        }
        echo '<br/><br/>';
        // ---------- CONNECTIONS INFORMATION
        $answer = $oauth2->getGuildsInformation();
        if (array_key_exists("code", $answer)) {
            exit("An error occured: " . $answer["message"]);
        } else {
            foreach ($answer as $a) {
                echo $a["permissions"] . ': ' . $a["name"] . '<br/>';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I would truely love if i could limit users based on permissions,

between yes i watched the discord api docs c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finnaly founded, using a mask.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

For exemple you get an permission id of 67 = 64 + 2 + 1 it will do true

```php
if ($a["permissions"] & "64") {
   echo "Can Ban";
}
```